# Pass parameters to git pre-push hook

Tags: git, githooks

I've create a git pre-push hook that builds my .NET solution and runs the unit tests. So executing a `git push` command now fires off the build/tests prior to pushing code to origin.

That all works just fine. However, there are cases when I'd like to bypass this hook. Maybe I know a test is failing and that's fine for now, I'd just like to be able to skip the logic in my hook.

Ideally I'd be able to do something like this:

`git push --skip-tests`

However, that doesn't seem to fly because git flags `--skip-tests` as an invalid parameter. Is there a way I can pass a parameter into the hook from the command line when doing a push so that I can branch the hook logic based on whether that parameter exists or not?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should skip it with:

```
git push --no-verify
```

From [`git push` man page](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push)

> With `--no-verify`, the hook is bypassed completely.

---

However, this bypass not just the tests but the all hook: build too.

You could keep the hook, but add an environment variable that the hook script would detect in order to build but not test.

```
skip-test=true git push
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you! In this particular case, bypassing the hook completely will work, although it's nice to have the ability to skip portions of it.

Comment: @Scott I have edited the answer to point to an alternative too.